# PHP emails with CSS not working on gmail

Tags: css, gmail, html-email

I already read lots of threads about this and they all say that gmail doesnt support the style tag so I have to use the inline styling to resolve the problem. The problem is that I've look at the source code on most of the emails that I've received on gmail and most of them use the css style tag, which contradicts what other says.

So question is, why the emails with css that I've send via php mail is not showing correctly on gmail. It does show ok on Yahoo and Hotmail though

Comment: This is very vague...what is working and what isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit hard to provide a detailed answer to a question that doesn't provide specifics so I'll make some general comments...

Cross web-browser designing is a piece of cake compared to designing HTML emails for different e-mail clients. There are far more email clients than web-browsers and far more variation in their support of HTML and CSS rendering. There are no "standards" per-se.

You need to keep everything simple and play to the lowest common element. It's not just a matter of the `style` tag being implemented or not, different client may or may not support different styles. You need to experiment with what works and what doesn't on as many clients as possible.

Some more reading for you if you haven't read these already:

- http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/13/techniques-overcome-poor-css-support-email/

Comment: I cant reveal more because this is work related. So I made a html file with css content, the basic one, in it with the style tag within the head tag, It looks really great when I view it in any web browser, and thunderbird. But when viewed on gmail it looks horrible. the email contains around 150 lines of css code so inlining everything would be bad in case we want to change it in the future. On the other hand, things like youtube, dell, and such that sends fancy emails to gmail gets their css context within the style tag. You can even see it if you click the 'Show original' option in gmail.

Comment: Its not that the css context is bad enough to 'parse' it in a browser, its just that I dont see an answer as to why majority of emails get their style tag removed while a few emails like those from Youtube dont, unless they pay Google to make an exception

Comment: Youtube and Dell have vastly more resources than your average programming monkey like myself. With your observations is there inline styles as well as the `style` tag? If so their mail automating services may be automagically "inlining" the styles. @John makes references to this kind of service in his blog post.

Answer (score 1):

Many people design with their CSS in the style tag and then use a tool to inline it prior to sending, making it compatible with for Gmail. Depending on the tool, it may not remove the original css, effectively doubling up. Another reason could be that those css declarations are intended for non-Gmail clients. A common example is media queries, which don't work inline, making them incompatible with Gmail.

Here is a related [blog post](http://dzyncreative.tumblr.com/post/39668246864/inline-your-email-css) I've written that also includes a few links to some popular CSS inlining tools